# Could I ask an ex-advisor to show me the letter of recommendation he wrote for me?

Tags: advisor, etiquette, recommendation-letter, cv, europe

Is it possible to ask somebody who wrote me a letter of recommendation to show me the letter? or is it impolite in academia? - The letter is a requirement to participate in a top networking conference in mathematics.

I asked an ex-advisor who I have always felt that he didn't like me personally but I was one of his top students, if not the best in class. I have a strong feeling that he wrote me a weak one.

Comment: What country? .

Comment: I am applying to a conference in Europe (Germany). The one who wrote me the letter was taught in Europe too (France).

Comment: It is unwise to ask someone who you do not trust to write you an RL. On the other hand, a proposed referee should suggest that the applicant seek another referee if they cannot write a letter that helps the applicant. Sometimes, there is none, but at least they should advise the applicant to seek a reference elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

It would be considered impolite, especially if they had the expectation that you would not have access to the letter when you requested it. If you don't trust that they're writing you a strong enough letter, it's probably best to search hard to arrange an alternative.

I'll mention briefly two work-arounds to this situation that I've seen happen, in case they somehow line up.

- In some countries you may be legally entitled to request to see the letters you sent in for an application, especially if you've joined a program on the basis of those letters.
- If you joined a program where your advisor's letter was sent, and there's someone you trust quite highly in that new organization with access to it, you may be able to ask this new person for their assessment of the letter's strength. This at least gets you the information you want (how strong is the letter?) without telling you any of the actual content.